# Java - Correct way to scale an image

Tags: java, image, memory, garbage-collection, javax.imageio

**Context**

I'm reviewing some legacy Java code that's used in a server-side application to scale images.  Until recently it has predominately been used with input images that possessed resolutions of 1024x768 or below, and in this context it seems to have worked well (or at least, well enough).

Now, however, many of the images being manipulated have resolutions ranging from 2592x1936 (8MP) to 6000x4000 (24MP).  This has led to frequent `OutOfMemoryError`'s being reported on the server, which I believe are being caused by the image manipulation code.

**Testcase**

I've put together a simple test application that calls into the image-processing code the same way that the server does (with one caveat; the testcase is single-threaded while the server environment obviously is not):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("test_fullres.png");     //8MP test image, PNG format
    for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
        File output = new File("target/images/img_" + index + ".jpg");
        verifyImageIsValidAndScale(file, output, 1024, 768, true, 80);

        if (index % 10 == 0) {
            String memStats = "Memstats after " + index + " iterations:";
            memStats += "\tFree Memory:  " + (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MBytes\n";
            memStats += "\tTotal Memory:  " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MBytes\n";
            memStats += "\tMax Memory:  " + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MBytes\n";

            System.out.println(memStats);
        }
    }
}
```

So pretty basic, just loops 1000 times and scales an input image on each iteration, outputting some memory stats every 10 iterations.  I've also set the following JVM flags:

`-verbose:gc -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=3000`

For a control, I've used a 1024x768 JPEG as the source input.  For the actual test I'm using an 8MP PNG image is input.

**Code**

The rest of the code under test is:

```
public static boolean verifyImageIsValidAndScale(File in, File out, int width, int height, boolean aspectFit, int quality){
    boolean valid = verifyImageIsValid(in);
    aspectFitImage(in, out, width, height, quality);

    return valid;
}

public static boolean verifyImageIsValid(File file){
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        stream = new FileInputStream(path);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[11];

        int numRead = stream.read(buffer);

        if(numRead > 3 && buffer[1] == 'P' && buffer[2] == 'N' && buffer[3] == 'G') {
            stream.close();
            buffer = null;
            LOG.debug("Valid PNG");
            return ImageIO.read(new File(path)) != null;    //PNG
        } else if (numRead > 10 && ((buffer[6] == 'J' && buffer[7] == 'F' && buffer[8] == 'I' && buffer[9] == 'F' && buffer[10] == 0) || 
                (buffer[6] == 'E' && buffer[7] == 'x' && buffer[8] == 'i' && buffer[9] == 'f' && buffer[10] == 0))){
            stream.close();
            buffer = null;
            LOG.debug("Valid JPEG");
            return ImageIO.read(new File(path)) != null;    //JPEG
        }
        buffer = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        try {
            stream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }
    LOG.debug("Invalid Image");
    return false;
}

public static Image aspectFitImage(File uploadedFile, File outputFile, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, int quality) {
    if (quality < 0) {
        quality = 0;
    }

    Image scaledImage = null;
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(uploadedFile);
        double scaleX = image.getWidth() > maxWidth ? maxWidth / (double)image.getWidth() : 1.0;
        double scaleY = image.getHeight() > maxHeight ? maxHeight / (double)image.getHeight() : 1.0;
        double useScale = scaleX < scaleY ? scaleX : scaleY;

        scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance((int)(image.getWidth() * useScale), (int)(image.getHeight() * useScale), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        //XXX:  getting bizarre results where overwriting a pre-existing output file doesn't properly overwrite the existing file; explicitly deleting the output file when it already exists seems to solve the issue
        if (outputFile.exists()) {
            outputFile.delete();
        }

        ImageOutputStream imageOut = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputFile);
        ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();

        ImageWriteParam options = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        options.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        options.setCompressionQuality(quality / 100.0f);

        PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(scaledImage, 0, 0, -1, -1, true);
        pg.grabPixels();

        DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferInt((int[]) pg.getPixels(), pg.getWidth() * pg.getHeight());
        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(buffer, pg.getWidth(), pg.getHeight(), pg.getWidth(), RGB_MASKS, null);
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(RGB_OPAQUE, raster, false, null);

        writer.setOutput(imageOut);
        writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bi, null, null), options);
        imageOut.close();
        writer.dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        uploadedFile.delete();  
        return null;
    }

    return scaledImage;
}
```

Furthermore, I've found that if I start commenting out code until the only nontrivial line that's left is:

`BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(uploadedFile);`

...the results are still basically the same in terms of the final memory tallies.

**Results**

Below if the final output from each run, both from the GC logs and the built-in memory logging statements:

```
#Source @ 1024x768 (control)
[GC pause (young) 1333M->874M(1612M), 0.0016051 secs]
Memstats after 990 iterations:  Free Memory:  505.5521469116211 MBytes
    Total Memory:  1612.0 MBytes
    Max Memory:  6144.0 MBytes


#Source @ 2592x1936 (test):
[GC pause (young) 2161M->1610M(2632M), 0.0025038 secs]
Memstats after 990 iterations:  Free Memory:  425.37239837646484 MBytes
    Total Memory:  2632.0 MBytes
    Max Memory:  6144.0 MBytes
```

Both seem higher than that should be.  And what's not captured here is that during the test run the garbage collector would frequently be reclaiming upwards of 1GB of memory at a time.

Perhaps also noteworthy is that the 'total memory' value gradually creeps higher and higher as the run progresses, as if the garbage collector isn't able to reclaim all of the memory that's being churned through.  So perhaps that implies a memory leak?

On average the garbage collector appears to trigger every 2-3 loop iterations.  And in any case the amount of churn seems fairly unreasonable, given that I'm scaling the images serially on a single thread.  This shouldn't be something that burns through gigabytes and gigabytes of memory.  Even if behind the scenes Java is unpacking every image to a 32-bit bitmap I wouldn't expect memory usage to climb as quickly as observed.

**Questions**

- What's the correct/most memory-efficient way to scale high-resolution images in Java?
- Is there an obvious bug in the legacy code, or should I just scrap it and rewrite?
- Would I be better off spawning an external process to perform the image manipulation (for instance if Java is just intrinsically unsuited for this use-case for some reason)?

Comment: First of all, even though you put a lot of effort into this question, I'm not sure if it fits SO. Perhaps Code Review would be a better place to post it? Both item 1 and 3 are typically "it depends" kind of questions that would need further background, and are likely to create opinionated answers. For example, I can scale high-res images super-fast and with very little memory at the expense of image quality. But I don't know what your quality requirements are. For item 3, what is "better" for you is, in my opinion, very much dependent on the expertise in your team.

Comment: @haraldK - Even if I pare the code down so that the only thing left is a `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(uploadedFile);`, the results are basically the same.  So I think this question is less about code review, and more about "is `BufferedImage`/`ImageIO` fundamentally unscalable due to how it internally manages memory?".  And the answer I'm leaning towards is "yes".  Based on what I'm seeing, you can't do _anything_ super-fast and with very little memory using the classes that exist under the `javax.image` package.

Comment: The `ImageIO` API has a lot of more "fine-grained" ways of controlling how images are read, using the `ImageReader` subclasses. You don't need to use `ImageIO.read(..)` and read the entire image (your legacy code does it *twice* by the way). You can read the images subsampled, which will be faster and use less memory than reading the whole image. I know people are writing image servers in Java, so I think the *"fundamentally unscalable"* statement is unfounded. :-)

Comment: PS: It might be that for your use case (and with your experience/gut feeling), spawning off to an external process is just the right thing to do. I know people are doing that successfully too (typically using ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick). It's just a whole different beast, with it's own set of quirks and issues.

Comment: @haraldK - That's basically where I went with it.  I offloaded the scaling operation to imagemagick.  And apart from producing the scaled images, the only other thing the application actually cares about is knowing the width/height of each image file.  So I put together some tweaked code using an `ImageReader` to pull in just the dimension info without reading the entire file into a `BufferedImage`, and that seems to be working much better.

Comment: I finally found the time to run your test app, and by adding a `System.gc()` to the end and printing the memory stats again I got `[Full GC 741M->540K(7168K), 0.1173000 secs]
Memstats after 1000 iterations: Free Memory:  6.4516754150390625 MBytes
 Total Memory:  7.0 MBytes
 Max Memory:  4096.0 MBytes
`. Meaning, all memory is reclaimed and given back to the host OS. So, other than some obvious inefficiencies in the legacy code, I don't think there was a reason to ditch Java here. :-)